# Transferring Xbox rewards

Tags: xbox-360

We currently have 10,000 rewards points from the past.  Just set the account up but the points have not transferred.  How do we do this?

Comment: Are you trying to transfer the points between accounts?  I'm afraid that's not possible.

Comment: "Just set *the* account up" What account? A new one? The old one on a new box?

Answer (score 2):

Whether you mean achievement points or credit, neither transfer to new Xbox accounts.

Instead, simply sign in to the original account. Everything will transfer across, including achievements, credit, and backwards-compatible games.

You may also be signed in to the same account on an Xbox One, while you are also signed in on an Xbox 360.